# What is the default Content-Type in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, content-type

I have created a [javascript library](http://umbrellajs.com/) and I am setting manually the [Content-Type](https://github.com/umbrellajs/umbrella/blob/master/umbrella.js#L367) right now. I would love to know what is the default *Content-Type*. The [XHR documentation](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) for [the send() method](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send%28%29-method) is confusing at best:

> **4.** If body is null, go to the next step. Otherwise ...
>
> > BodyInit
> >
> > If body is a string, set encoding to `UTF-8`.
> >
> > Set request body and Content-Type to the result of extracting body.

Where, [the result of extracting body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract) for a text is:

- Blob
- BufferSource
- FormData
- URLSearchParams
- USVString

So, which of these types would it be? The `body` passed to `send()` is in the default, escaped format of `a=b&c=d`. Is it a `URLSearchParams`? or a `USVString`? or a `Blob`? There's a description on each one but it's too cryptic for me to understand (I only know that it's probably not a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)).

Note: please provide some official documentation if possible

Comment: @adeneo thanks for the comment, but why? do you know any reference? Is that by the specificaction, cross-browser, or just browser-specific?

Comment: I think it isn't sent. If you check the examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests), there's no `Content-Type` being sent.

Comment: According to the spec, it seems it checks the charset, and if `null` sets it to `UTF8`, and then checks "final MIME type" and sets that, usually that would be `text/html`, meaning the `Content-type` is set to something like `text/html; charset=utf-8.`

Comment: @MinusFour — The example you link to sets a content-type.

Comment: @Quentin, yeah I had a bad link it's fixed.

Comment: @MinusFour — The new example you link to is a GET request, it doesn't have a request body to set the content-type of.

Comment: What you linked to says that if the value is a string, the content type is set to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: @FelixKling — That matches what I observe if I try `var f = new XMLHttpRequest();f.open("POST", "", false);f.send("test=test");`

Comment: @MinusFour & @Quentin yes, GET requests just ignores `Content-type` and some other headers

Comment: @MinusFour also it says *the only headers which are allowed to be manually*. This says that the user can set them manually, but it has nothing to do apparently with the default value if not set manually.

Comment: @FelixKling it specifies only the `USVString` string type. But `URLSearchParams`, for instance, appears to be also the desired string. That's why I'm confused

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia, right... I only meant to show up the request example there (the actuual petitions). I just didn't realize that there wouldn't be any sense on setting a `Content-Type` for a  petition that doesn't send any content.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia — https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlsearchparams — it's a specific kind of object

Comment: If you click on the `URLSearchParams` link (what @Quentin posted), then you will see that the `URLSearchParams` object has a specific interface which generic strings don't have. Hence a string cannot be a `URLSearchParams` object / value.

Comment: Okay I see, [it's a completely different thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). So it should be `USVString` then, thanks. I'll test it to check that it holds true cross-browser, thanks for all the comments/help!

Answer (score 3):

[Directly from the horse's mouth](http://w3c-test.org/XMLHttpRequest/send-content-type-charset.htm), if you are sending a string their last test expects `"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"` [in accordance with the XMLHttpRequest Level 1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-XMLHttpRequest-send-a-string).

So you will have to refer to the step four of the [send method](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send()-method) to know exactly what is expected depending on the data.