# CORS error in using XMLHttpRequest while using Axios avoid the issue

Tags: api, http, xmlhttprequest, preflight

I am just starting to learn how to make requests to APIs using Javascript, and I have been stuck on the following for a few hours.

I used the following public API:
http://www.penguinrandomhouse.biz/webservices/rest/

The issue is that, when I was using XMLHttpRequest, I am always running into an error. At first I didn’t include the content-type in header I got a 404, and when I included it, the error I have got a CORS error.
The following is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Request book</title>
    <style>
    ...
    </style>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="preview">
      <div id="return_content"></div>
    </section>
    <script>
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const url = "https://reststop.randomhouse.com/resources/authors";
      request.open("GET", url);
      let content = {
        lastName : "Grisham",
      }
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      /* I did not add this at first, but it seems like the 
      default content type for XHR is not what the API wants*/
      request.send(JSON.stringify(content));
      request.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
          console.log(request.responseText);
          /* let content_div = document.querySelector('#return_content');
          content_div.innerText = request.responseText; */
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

The error message is as the following:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://reststop.randomhouse.com/resources/authors. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200
```

But I tried sending the request first with Axios in node.js with the following, it goes totally fine; so I assume it must be something wrong with my request. However, from my understanding the CORS policy should be set by the server, and it seems like from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23272690/9882001) I cannot set Access-Control-Allow-Origin — it is supposed to be something provided by the server-side.

It seems like something is missing in the request but I really have no idea. Any help or hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I didn’t go through all the documents… I kept reading about the API but didn’t go through the CORS MDN page in detail.
Anyway I will just leave it here in case anyone need this in the future.

Quoted from MDN:
`For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web application using those APIs can only request resources from the same origin the application was loaded from unless the response from other origins includes the right CORS headers.`

I think this means the CORS policy is a way for the browser to protect itself from malicious scripts too, most likely the ones that aims for the cookies stored in browser.

What I found the most confusing is that the error message changed before and after I added content-type in header. What happened back there, was that I made a “simple request” without knowing it(from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952304/what-is-the-default-content-type-in-xmlhttprequest), the default content type is text-plain), which is why it didn’t trigger the CORS policy but only gave me a 404.